# How to set up a laravel project on cPanel subdomain?

Tags: laravel, git, cpanel

I am new to cPanel and wanted to know which is the best way to host a Laravel project on a subdomain. I created the subdomain already with its root in the home directory. My client has other websites in the public_html folder and I don't want to mess with them. How should I proceed? 
Also, if you could tell me what is the best way to manage a website in cpanel in terms of continuous integration and version control, I would appreciate it. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In root directory in the domains home directory (one up from the public_html) you need to create folder for example **laravel_project**

**sub_domain_folder** is folder of your sub_domian that works like public_html for your second site.

Host schematic:

```
- root directory
    - laravel_project
    - ...
    - public_ftp
    - public_html
         -- ... (other sub_domains_folders + files for main site)
         -- sub_domian_folder
```

(Step 1) - upload all of your laravel application files and folders in laravel_project **except** public folder

(Step 2) - Just copy all files in your laravel application **public** folder (css - js - .htaccess - index.php - ...) in sub_domain_folder

(Step 3) - Now you need to edit your index.php file that locate in **sub_domain_folder** (Step 2) as below:

```
require __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';

$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/app.php';
```

change to:

```
require __DIR__.'/../../laravel_project/vendor/autoload.php';

$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../../laravel_project/bootstrap/app.php';
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. Do I need to change the root of the subdomain folder I created to point to any of these new folders (laravel_project or sub_domain_folder) ?

Comment: Also, do I need to manually create sub_domain_folder inside the public_html folder?

Comment: No...when you create sub domian in direct-admin or cPanel this folder create automatically in public_html for you...sub_domain_folder is just folder that create automatically with your subdomain name @dan