# laravel project on cpanel subdomain error: HTTP ERROR 500

Tags: php, laravel, cpanel

I have a confusing error with laravel 7  project. This project when I uploaded it into the main directory It worked successfully. but when I uploaded it into a subdomain it gives me 500 error.
I did steps that mentioned in this answer but it didn't work also
[How to set up a laravel project on cPanel subdomain?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59236424/how-to-set-up-a-laravel-project-on-cpanel-subdomain)
Hope someone help me
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: What's an error 500 tell ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First Of All, I'd like to thank all contributors.
I knew the reason for the error.
In this image:
[![enter image description here][1]][1]

The file called `public_html` is not in the root directory as it might seem it is.
It's just a shortcut from : `/domains/zigzagfamily.com/public_html`
So when I created a folder called `chatbot` in `public_html`,
I wrote in `index.php`:

`require __DIR__.'/../../chatbot/vendor/autoload.php';`

`$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../../chatbot/bootstrap/app.php';`

And it's wrong because as I said `public_html` is here:

`/domains/zigzagfamily.com/public_html`
So when I go back two folders, I'm now in `zigzagfamily.com`
So I must go back another two folders to be in the root directory to be able to access `chatbot` folder that is located in the root directory.
Summery: the right code was:

`require __DIR__.'/../../../../chatbot/vendor/autoload.php';`

`$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../../../../chatbot/bootstrap/app.php';`

Answer (score 0):

Laravel project start form `public` folder.

Bad practice to start it from root.

You must place your project into root of hosting (at the same level as the `public_html` folder), then remove `public_html` folder and create next symbolic link.

run command in terminal hosting root

```
    ln -s your_project_folder/public public_html
```

In this case your no need edit index.php files.

If you planing to use any deployer in the future I recommend to use next folders structure:

```
    /public_html <- link to 
    /sites/your_project_name/current/public
```

and save your main current project in `current` folder.

Answer (score 0):

Since laravel uses pretty URLs, using zigzagfamily.com/chatbot will not work.

In your cPanel create a subdomain (chatbot.zigzagfamily.com) pointing to */public_html/chatbot*

Into the */public_html/chatbot* folder, upload/move your */chatbot/public* content.

Modify your /public_html/chatbot/index.php file from:

```
require __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';
$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/app.php';
```

To:

```
require __DIR__.'/../../chatbot/vendor/autoload.php';
$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../../chatbot/bootstrap/app.php';
```

Finally, Be shure that the bootstrap folder and storage folder have 0775 permission (for testing).