# How to set up a Laravel App with Subdomains to work on a cPanel server?

Tags: laravel, apache, cpanel

*First of all: this is not a duplicate of ([How to set up a laravel project on cPanel subdomain?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59236424/how-to-set-up-a-laravel-project-on-cpanel-subdomain)) this question isn't the same as mine.*

I would like to know how can i set up a whole Laravel application, with subdomains (not only one subdomain) to work on a cPanel server

So here is the test code i'm using on my `routes/web.php` file.

```php
Route::domain('test.mydomain.com')->group(function() {
    Route::get('/', function() {
        return 'DOMAIN TEST.MYDOMAIN.COM';
    });
});

Route::domain('mydomain.com')->group(function() {
    Route::get('/', function() {
        return 'DOMAIN MYDOMAIN.COM';
    });
});

Route::get('/', function() {
    return 'ROOT DOMAIN';
});
```

I'm currently using cPanel to handle domains and subdomains, but i have no idea how to make it work with Laravel Subdomains, i tried the code above.

When i access my main domain `mydomain.com` it shows "DOMAIN MYDOMAIN.COM" so it works ok, but when i go to `test.mydomain.com` it just access my subdomain folders from this subdomain, so, how can i make it works?

Maybe i need to put some `.htaccess` file to get this working properly? Can someone help?

Comment: You will need * / wildcard the domain in order for domains to work in your DNS setup

Comment: @Tithira But how can i define the name of the subdomains so? How Laravel will know what route to redirect if it's a wildcard? If i have `test.mydomain.com` and `test2.mydomain.com` and i set up to a wildcard `*.mydomain.com` how can i define my routes to each one of these two subdomains?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try to link subdomains to the same folder as primary domain ?
Eg.

domain.com => /public_html/public

test.domain.com => /public_html/public